# Android Studio compiles old icon

Tags: android, icons, android-studio

I started an Android project using the default icon (`ic_launcher`) using Android Studio. But now I want to change the icon to something else. I tried replacing all the `ic_launcher.png`s in the project directory, copying the icons under a new name and change the `AndroidManifest.xml` but the app still has the old `ic_launcher`. I also tried restarting Android Studio, Invalidate Cache and Restart, uninstall the app from the device but the icon never changed.

PS : Removing the `android:icon="@drawable/logo"` (NOTE : I changed `ic_launcher.png` to `logo.png` to see if it works then) changed the icon to the default android icon. But putting it back still gives me the same old one.

Is there a different procedure to change the icon of an app using Android Studio?

Comment: If you would have been using eclipse, I would have advised you to clean the project. Haven't used Android Studio though.

Comment: Have you tried importing launcher icons to respective folders using add drawable?

Comment: Reboot your phone, it solved the problem for me.

Comment: Yep , Clean project, Sync Gradles and phone reboot solve the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what is the exact problem (Android Studio even showed the correct icon in the preview despite the app having the incorrect icon) but I resolved it by copying the same icon under a different name and changing the Manifest accordingly.

Comment: Any IDE, whether Eclipse, Android Studio, etc, require you to refresh the project's tree to see new resources like images, text files, etc. Perhaps you forgot to refresh your project before you build.

Comment: It's 2020, we are all inside, and still this issue exists :|

Comment: For me what worked was adding `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_app_round"` after `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_app"`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in Android Studio. All that was required was selecting `Build -> Clean Project` from the menu and then build again. After that, the correct icon appeared in the compiled APK file.

Answer (score 4):

In **Android Studio 3.6** I was also facing the same problem. I just restarted my phone and every thing was fine. I hope that you just have to restart your phone.

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio 1.5.1, here what worked for me :

1. Add this line in manifest application part after the label

   `android:label="@string/my_app"`

   `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`
2. Clean your app
3. Restart your phone
4. Launch it, it should be OK!

Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need to do to ensure that this won't happen again.

**step 1:**
delete all ic_launcher files from drawable + mipmap .

**step 2:**
put your assets/svg to drawable (or mipmap if you want)

**step 3:**
clean project

**step 4:**
if the above 3 steps doesn't help you , restart your phone, you will now see the new icons. In my case i tried everything but nothing worked, at last when i restarted my phone, everything worked fine, this was because android was using cached state to show the old icons.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that although I had all of the correct image files/sizes for my icon. I also had the default ic_launcher.xml file in my folder. The build was referencing this as the logo instead of any image I tried.

My solution: 
-Delete the ic_launcher.xml file
-Add your icon image and reference it in your AndroidManifest.xml

ex: android:icon="@mipmap/example_icon"

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the SVG file I was using to create the image asset. I created a new SVG file with no errors then it worked fine, I also tried to change the SVG file to a PNG file and it worked like charm! I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the phone. If that does not solve the problem, then refactor->rename the package. Both methods solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the APP package on top left side , make sure  it is the  same app for which you want to change the icon.
2. After clicking on it ,go to NEW and then to  "image asset" option.
   there you can change the icon by selecting the image or the clip art you want.
3. Then just click the next  and finish buttons to add the respective image.
   run the app and if the icon is not changing, uninstall the app  and then again run the app, after which the app will be reinstalled and the icon would be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio provides resource files that have the same name as the PNG icons (eg. `ic_launcher.xml` & `ic_launcher_rounded.xml`).
If take a look at any of those files you'll notice that it references other resources from the drawable directory like `ic_launcher_background.xml` and `ic_launcher_foreground.xml`. So, the manifest actually references those file, which hides your custom icons if they have the same name. To fix this issue, you can either delete the resource files or rename your custom icons.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was having two 'ic_launcher_foreground.xml' files in the drawable folder, one with correct logo and the other with old logo, deleting the old logo fixed it

Answer (score 0):

In you `AndroidManifest.xml` file, under `<application`  make sure both `android:icon=` and `android:roundIcon=` point to the correct asset

Answer (score 0):

If you used Image Asset Studio and kept the name the same as the default icon, or edited the default files directly, Android Studio may be ignoring your PNG files and using the "anydpi" vector files.

If you haven't changed those, try renaming or deleting the related .xml files in:

`app > res > drawable > mipmap`

eg: rename the default files:

`ic_launcher.xml` `ic_launcher_round.xml`

to

`x_ic_launcher.xml` `x_ic_launcher_round.xml`

and it should now pick up the appropriate PNG file instead.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be sure in your manifest you have android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" under the main activity like this